# Can I use STDistance in a function?

Tags: php, sql, sql-function

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two coordinates, so I want to use STDistance. Can I use STDistance in a function using two variables as coordinates? I'm trying to call the function in php so that's why I want it to be an SQL function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION measureDistance(@coordsFrom INT, @coordsTo INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @g geography;  
DECLARE @h geography;  
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(@coordsFrom)', 4326);  
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(@coordsTo)', 4326);  
RETURN @g.STDistance(@h);
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use PHP functions in SQL functions. But you can get the coordinates from the DB, set them to some variables in your PHP and to the calculation there.